# Best place to store model specific constants in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a field **type** in a model called **user** which is an int in the db. The value of the int speficies the type of store it is. Example:

- 0 = mom
- 1 = dad
- 2 = grand mother
- and so on

I have several other fields like this so it's overkill to create association tables.

Instead of checking for those int values over the place in conditional statements in model and controller logic, is there a place in rails to store these constants.

So that I could do this from my models and controllers?

```
if myuser.type == MOM
elsif myuser.type == GRAND_MOTHER
```

**EDIT: Solution I went with at the end:**

In model:

```
  # constants
  TYPES = {
    :mom => 0,
    :dad => 1,
    :grandmother => 2,
    :grandfather => 3
  }
```

In logic:

```
if u.type == User::TYPES[:mom]
```

Even though it's longer, I felt it to be more intuitive for other developers when they're reading my code. Thanks to Taro below for this solution.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  TYPES = %w{ mom dad grandmother grandfather son }

  TYPES.each_with_index do |meth, index|
    define_method("#{meth}?") { type == index }
  end

end


u = User.new
u.type = 4
u.mom? # => false
u.son? # => true
```

Comment: Great solution. Is there a way to use the values in the assignment though? Something like... `u.type = MOM` ... otherwise in case a value changed over time would require edits to that value in multiple files.

Comment: Put the constant inside the class and refer to it as `User::MOM`.

Comment: Is it possible to use this same notation to access method in a model without creating the object first like in PHP? I get a "undefined method" error if I do something like `ModelName::mydef()`

Comment: In order to make object respond to any message, you should define method_missing method.

Comment: I would prefer to create individual constant which is more readable.

Answer (score 12):

Since Rails 4.1, there is support for [ActiveRecord::Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

There's a useful tutorial [here](https://richonrails.com/articles/active-record-enums-in-ruby-on-rails-4-1), but in short:

```
# models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum family_role: [ :mum, :dad, :grandmother]
end

# logic elsewhere
u = User.first
u.family_role = 'mum'
u.mum? # => true
u.family_role # => 'mum'
```

Note: To convert from your current scheme (where your database already stores numbers corresponding to values), you should use the hash syntax:

```
enum family_role: { mum: 0, dad: 1, grandmother: 2 }
```

I would additionally propose that you reserve `0` for the default state, but that's just one convention and not critical.

Comment: And yes - I know this doesn't help with your Rails 3.1 specific question, but hope it helps others.

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid using "type" as a model's column name unless you use Single Table Inheritance.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance

Answer (score 1):

One way you be to write an file in initializers folder or lib folder

say **app_contants.rb** and in this file you can write

```
MOM=1

DAD=2
```

1. Incase you write a initializer
   you can do

> user.type == mom

2.If you create an lib file 
 make it a module

```
 module app_constants
    mom = 1
    dad = 2
  end
```

and simply include this module wherever you need

Comment: since all the constants I want are related to fields in models, would it be a good practice to include the respective modules in their models? Also, would those constants then be available in any controller or rake file that uses those models?