# Rails: constant in initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to keep constants in initializer and use it in model like:

model:

```
class AssessmentProcedure < ActiveRecord::Base

  def default_values
    self.self_estimation_weight ||= PROCEDURES_CONFIG['self_estimation_weight']
    self.parent_estimation_weight ||= PROCEDURES_CONFIG['parent_estimation_weight']
  end

end
```

config/initializers/constants.rb

```
PROCEDURES_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/assessment_procedures.yml")
```

The problem is when I use it I get an exception:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant AssessmentProcedure::PROCEDURES_CONFIG
```

What did I miss? Thanks

Comment: you can use it in model `PROCEDURES_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/assessment_procedures.yml")` instead of initializers

Comment: @RajarshiDas I know, but it's a bad practice to keep constants in model

Comment: I defined constants in an initializer in a rails 3.2 project with syntax MENU_CONFIG = Rails.root.join("config", "menu.yml").open { |file| YAML::load(file) } and its working quite well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026344/best-place-to-store-model-specific-constants-in-rails-3-1

Comment: model specific constant ...not globalize constant

Comment: replace `PROCEDURES_CONFIG['self_estimation_weight']` on `::PROCEDURES_CONFIG['self_estimation_weight']`

Comment: @irene thanks, but there's the same problem

Comment: @itsnikolay same problem

Comment: @PavelBabin probably restarting of the server can resolve it?

Comment: @itsnikolay I try it in console and I've reloaded it

Answer (score 2):

try

```
self.self_estimation_weight ||= ::PROCEDURES_CONFIG['self_estimation_weight']
```

it will unscope the constant and use the global namespace

In Rail 4.2 there is a much cleaner way

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.x.procedures_config.self_estimation_weight = 4711
```

See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html about custom configuration options